# Does anyone know if the source code for http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home is available?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Does anyone know if the source code for http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home is available?

I am trying to call Google Closure Compiler from a Java application and I'm thinking that if the source code for the service above would be available somewhere i could see how this was implemented I could have an idea of how to do it myself.

Comment: Is [this what you're referring to](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/#git/closure/goog)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't - the web service isn't open source.